# Roots of the derivative as symmetric (?) functions of the roots of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-functions

Let $p(t)=(t^2-a_1^2)\ldots(t^2-a_n^2)$ be an even polynomial with distinct real non-zero roots. Can the roots of its derivative $p'(t)$ be expressed nicely (e.g. as rational symmetric functions) in terms of the roots of $p(t)$? How?

Comment: I think the answer is generally no. For example, see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt%28t%5E2-1%29%28t%5E2-4%29%28t%5E2-9%29%28t%5E2-16%29%28t%5E2-25%29%28t%5E2-36%29%3D0), where $a_1 = 1, \dots, a_6=6$. The non-trivial solutions to $p'(t)=0$ are roots to quintic equations.

Comment: Yes, I supposed there will be problems starting at $n=6$ but take into account that wolfram just looks at the value of the coefficients ignoring that they are symmetric functions in the $a_i$'s that we know. Maybe that extra information could help?

Comment: Even the roots of $p$ itself cannot be expressed as _symmetric_ functions of the roots of $p$ (though the coefficients of $p$ can). I think you must be confusing somthing. The coefficients of $p'$ can obviously be expressed as symmetric function of the roots of $p$.